# Count the Distinct Rows in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have the below query and I would like to find the distinct rows based on `studentID`, `examDesc`, `examGrade`, `schoolYear` and add an extra column with the count on the distinct rows.

```
StudentInfo
| join StudentExams on studentID
| project studentID, studentName, age, gender, examDesc, examGrade, schoolYear
```

I was wondering what's the syntax for this?

Comment: Try something like `| summarize gradeCount=count() by studentId, examDesc, examGrade, schoolYear`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [`count()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/count-aggfunction).

for example:

```
StudentExams 
| lookup StudentInfo on studentID // assuming not all information is in the 'StudentExams' table. otherwise, remove this line
| summarize count() by studentID, examDesc, examGrade, schoolYear
```

*[note: if this doesn't meet your requirement - it's strongly recommended that you provide a sample input data set, and the matching output for it, in order to clarify your desired outcome]*